# Horror B-movie themed RPG system?

Tags: game-recommendation, system-for-setting

I plan to do a single shot few hours long Horror B movie like RPG game, complete with popular clichés like [offscreen teleportation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OffscreenTeleportation), obvious continuity errors, out-of-the-blue, no sense making plot twists, cliché characters and so on.

Originally I planned to take any generic System like GURPS or even something like The Window should I feel like not bothering with mechanics. But maybe there's already a system designed specifically for this kind of game? I.e. Where all the cliches are somehow governed by systems mechanics, or something along these lines?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'v personally used Call of Cthulhu with the excellent Blood Brothers source book to do just this. Call of Cthulhu is easy to use, and it really gets transparent during play. Blood Brothers (and Blood Brothers 2, for that matter) are non-Mythos collections of B-Movie Horror tropes in scenario form. The first collection has Hammer Films, Zombie Outbreaks, Beach Blanket Horror, Slasher massacre, see where its going? Good stuff all around.

With CofC, you would have to do some of the cliche stuff yourself, aside from the well written scenarios which all have pre made characters that precisely follow the cliches of the genre. In fact, many of the plot twists are in the adventures themselves, now that I think about it. So, not just a game system, but a system and a sourcebook, is my first answer.

I just got the second edition of Monster of the Week. It is reading really well, and the play books (basically character classes, for those not in the know) for the characters are spot-on B Movie cliches, so genre tropes are built in pretty deep. I haven't played it yet, but I have played quite a bit of Dungeon World, which uses the same Apocalypse Engine that Monster of the Week uses, and I can vouch for it being quite malleable to what the players (including GM) want to do and when they want to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go digging around used game sites, there's "It Came From the Late Late Late Show" - which, while not perfect, isn't a bad stab at the genre.

Me, I'd just use Fate Core.

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago, there roamed upon this Earth a beast called *D20 Modern* that had rules and settings that could easily be adapted for such a game.  It used the OGL and was fully compatible with DnD 3.0 (and therefore, 3.5).

We ran a *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* themed game.  Cheesy fun jokes, monsters (I was a yuan-ti) and silliness abounded!

I'd highly recommend searching a Half-Price Books for it.

Comment: I have to second BtVS...excellent for what you want to do. There's no system stuff to emulate genre, but the tropes ripple throughout the system's flavor, if that makes any sense.